# Batch operating Google App Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I’m trying to write a simple script to adjust the values in a column. I know I could just ‘find’/‘replace’ this within sheets, but this is going to be built upon, and it would be easier for it to be done via a script. It will iterate over approx 10K rows.

However the below is timing out. I understand that setting the values each time, then looping through, is inefficient, however I can’t figure out how to batch it ([see here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/best-practices))

Below is the ‘inefficient’ / timing out code. Does anyone have a smart suggestion about how this can be resolved?

```
function stageModifier() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 
var activeSheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
var lastRow = activeSheet.getLastRow(); 
for (i = 2; i < lastRow; i++) {

    var data = activeSheet.getRange(i, 10)
    var cell = data.getValues();

    if (cell == "Unqualified") {
        data.setValue("1. Unqualified");
        if (cell == "Incoming") {
            data.setValue("2. Incoming");
            if (cell == "Qualified") {
                data.setValue("3. Qualified");
                if (cell == "Hot") {
                    data.setValue("4. Hot");
                    if (cell == "Selection") {
                        data.setValue("5. Selection");
                        if (cell == "Reservation") {
                            data.setValue("6. Reservation");
                            if (cell == "Deposit Invoice Out") {
                                data.setValue("7. Deposit Invoice Out");
                                if (cell == "Deposit 40% In") {
                                    data.setValue("8. Deposit 40% In");
                                    if (cell == "Cold") {
                                        data.setValue("9. Cold");
                                    };

                                };

                            };

                        };

                    };

                };
            };

        };

    };

};
SpreadsheetApp.flush()

};
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use [`getValues()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues) and [`setValues()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues) function of Range object.
**getValues():**
This will return the data in a 2D array like so

```
var data = activeSheet.getRange(1, 10,lastRow).getValues()
data = "[[Row1],[Row2],... [LastRow]]
```

To access Row1 data you would do `data[0][0]` 
**Note:** Immaterial of actual column/row number in the sheet, array index always starts from 0. 
**setValues()**
You access the data and modify the each individual element in the array by looping like so

```
for (i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {

            var cell = data[i][0]; //access values
            data[i][0] = "Jack Brown" //input new value to the array
  }
```

Once you have the modified the array, you can setValues of the cell in the sheet based on the array, like so:

```
activeSheet.getRange(1, 10,lastRow).setValues(data)
```

Your final code would look something like this:

```
function stageModifier() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 
    var activeSheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
    var lastRow = activeSheet.getLastRow(); 
    var data = activeSheet.getRange(1, 10,lastRow).getValues()
    for (i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {

        var cell = data[i][0];

        if (cell == "Unqualified") {
            data[i][0]= "1. Unqualified"
            // Modify the remaining the in the same fashion
            // Change all data.setValue to data[i][0] = "NEw value"
        }
    };
    // Now to set the values into the sheet
    activeSheet.getRange(1, 10,lastRow).setValues(data)
    SpreadsheetApp.flush()
    }
```

Comment: Great, thank you very much Jack. I had to make one small change to your final code to get it to work - instead of "for (i = 1; i < data.length(); i++)" I had to use "for (i = 1; i < lastRow; i++)" as it was throwing an error

Comment: @alastair budge Sorry about that, it should be `data.length` not `data.length()`. Thanks for the pointing it out.